# EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration and ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration in Spring Boot 2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, updates

when updating our project from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.0 the classes `EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration` and
`ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration` were gone, although we need them desperately. When I search the internet doe those classes, I can't find any replacements for this classes. So my question is: Have those classes been removed with Spring Boot 2.0? If not, where have they been moved to? Or how I can replace them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need them in the first place? Looks like you are doing things you shouldn't be doing in the first place. The classes got removed and/or renamed (the `ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration` has been removed the `EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration` got renamed/split into different classes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration** has been renamed to **ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration** by [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/67556ba8eaf22a352b03fe197a0c452f695835a6#diff-373f53029068c86e9e420173951a15c4L71) during work on [restructuring embedded web server packages](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8532).

**ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration** has been removed by [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/6af6e8e31bae8b982182eae70460fdf1612675a4#diff-17a44082235237309e8fdc3ed3e7b0f3) during work on [the following issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8108). Those properties objects are now created using
[@EnableConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/EnableConfigurationProperties.html) only.

Note: It might take some time for GitHub to show you particular line number.